# Handling foreach with key and value in php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have a **$row** array that will print the below array

```
        Array
        (
        [BookCode] => 124
        [BookName] => Book1
        )

        Array
        (
        [BookCode] => 123
        [BookName] => Book2
        )

        ...........
```

I have a code like this:

```
    <?php foreach($row as $key=>$value){  ?>
    <a href="process.php?bcode=<?php echo $value['BookCode'] ?>"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $value; ?></span></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

But I'm not able to get the BookCode in my anchor tag since I'm using foreach with key-value. In my case I have to use foreach only (as intructed by my client)

So how can I get the value inside the anchor tag?

Comment: could you redefine my code please

Comment: You need another loop nest inside: `foreach ( $row as $column ): foreach ( $column as $key=>$value )`

Comment: show the query that you write

Comment: deemi - i have got the answers. need not worry now ;)
see you with some other tuf question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop is not returning what you expect—you have an array of associative arrays.

```
<? foreach ( $row as $column ): ?>

  <a href="process.php?bcode=<?=$column['BookCode']?>">

<? endforeach; ?>
```

In the above, the link will be `process.php?bcode=124`

Alternatively, if you really want to use the `$key=>$value`:

```
<? foreach ( $row as $column ): ?>

  <? foreach ( $column as $key=>$value ) ?> // here $key = 'BookCode'
    <a href="process.php?bcode=<?=$value?>">
  <? endforeach; ?>

<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try foreach like this. It may help to you

```
foreach($row as $data)
{?>
    <a href="....<?php echo $data['Bookcode']; ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```